# MSP430 launchpad's bypass capacitor mystery!

Tags: capacitor, frequency, msp430, bypass-capacitor

I've been looking into MSP430 launchpad's schematics and saw something that can't quite understand: the bypass capacitors for the reset button and for the P1.3 are different (1nF and 100nF respectively).

[image: MSP430 schematics]

Since the noise frequencies generated from pressing any button would be (I assume) the same, wouldn't the value of the capacitors be the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SBWTDIO is a high frequency signal (used for programming the chip) which won't tolerate an 100nF cap. Remember that a cap in the data line results in longer signal rise and fall times.

Note the `DNP` on the C24 footprint: The 100nF cap is *not* mounted on the board.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea why isn't the 100nF capacitor on the board?